# "Bucket POST must contain a field named 'key'" error

Tags: go, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-sdk-go

I am trying to upload a file to s3 using a presigned POST URL (generated using boto3).

These are the fields in the generated presigned URL:

```
{"acl":"private",
"key":"4982bfe3-fae9-42a5-9502-4cc3fcd9ee87__swcli",
"x-amz-algorithm":
"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256",
"x-amz-credential":"AKIAICDC2ZVHRX25EYNQ/20180626/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request",
"x-amz-date":"20180626T014755Z",
"policy":"eyJleDE0NzU1WiJ9XX0=",
"x-amz signature":"f803ef38cbdd8a16"}
```

I am using this code to make the request

```
x := make(map[string]string)
x["key"],_ = jsonparser.GetString(*fields,"key")
x["acl"],_ = jsonparser.GetString(*fields,"acl")
x["x-amz-algorithm"],_ = jsonparser.GetString(*fields,"x-amz-algorithm")
x["x-amz-credential"],_ = jsonparser.GetString(*fields,"x-amz-credential")
x["x-amz-date"],_ = jsonparser.GetString(*fields,"x-amz-date")
x["policy"],_ = jsonparser.GetString(*fields,"policy")
x["x-amz-signature"],_ = jsonparser.GetString(*fields,"x-amz-signature")

c := new(http.Client)
req := request.NewRequest(c)
req.Data = x
f, err := os.Open("filewriter.go")
if err!=nil{
    fmt.Println("errored")
}

req.Files = []request.FileField{
    request.FileField{"file", "filewriter.go", f},
}
resp, err := req.Post("http://btrads-78.s3.amazonaws.com")
fmt.Println((resp.Text()))`
```

And receiving this error:
`Bucket POST must contain a field named 'key'.  If it is specified, please check the order of the fields.`

I have tried trying different combinations of order of `key` in x and using different HTTP client, but I am getting the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The field `x-amz-signature` has different key in the json. Is that relevant..?

Comment: I have manually checked parsing errors by printing out each value that gets passed into the form. Unfortunately, no error there!

Comment: Just to be sure, try `json.Unmarshal` for getting json into the map. It is less error prone than manually assigning each field.

Comment: Already tried! No luck there either.

Comment: not to be the annoying you want X try Y guy, but why do you not use the the aws go wrapper? https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go

Comment: @HarshGupta the `file` section must be the last one written to the form.